# Error when trigger download image on bootstrap button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a button that I want if user click the button, user will download an image directly.

Here's the code

```
 <a href="/path_to_image/" class="btn btn-xl btn-info btn-full-width" role="button" aria-pressed="true" style="margin-left:10px; width: 50px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Download Image" download>
    <i class="fi-br-download" style="display:contents; text-align:center;font-size:1rem"></i>
 </a>
```

The problem is when user click the button, the image is not download, but only show the image on browser.

Is there any solution ?

Comment: How are you testing your code, locally or on a server? If I run your code locally (just click an HTML file with you code in it), the a link will open in the browser, but if I upload the HTML file to my server (or run it locally via WAMP), then I get the prompt to download the file.

Comment: Hi @RichDeBourke I am testing in localhost and server, and the result is same

Comment: I just reconfirmed with the file I made with just your code and the Bootstrap style and JavaScript files I uploaded to my server. When I click the button in Firefox, I get a message from Firefox asking me what I want to do with the file. When I click the button in Chrome and Edge, the image is downloaded. In IE11, the image opens in the same tab, as IE11 doesn’t support download. I’m running Windows. — The only other thing I can think of to check would be the response headers when you download the image file. If Content-Disposition: inline, it would cause the image to open in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

download only works for same-origin URLs, or the blob: and data: schemes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a